# Creating a replication controller with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Reading through "Kubernetes In Action" book, there is a kubectl command which creates a pod but does not deploy it:

```
$ kubectl run kubia --image=dockeruser/kubia --port=8080 --generator=run/v1
replicationcontroller "kubia" created
```

The generator option is there to ensure that a replication controller is created and that there is no deployment. But in the version of kubectl that I am using, v1.22.3, the generator flag is deprecated. Leaving the generator option out will create the pod, but no replication controller.

Which command effectively creates the rc?

Comment: For anyone else coming across this whilst reading Kubernetes In Action — a second edition appears to be in the works and is set to be published in Summer 2020.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need "generator" starting 1.17, you can use "create" like `kubectl create deployment kubia --image=dockeruser/kubia --port=8080`

Comment: Where is the replication controller after running this command?

Comment: ReplicationController is not required here.

Comment: What if I wanted 3 pods of the same container, and if one went down it would come back up? (that's what the rc does) Is this possible thru deployements only?

Comment: To be precise, that is covered by ReplicaSet which in turn **manage** by Deployment. ReplicationController has no concept of update strategy, history etc like Deployment.